# Receiving multiple errors on the socket Java

Tags: java, sockets, exception, file-transfer

I am trying to create File Transfer system by using socket. My code used to work properly before I started sending a String fileName from server to Client to have the files in same name. Now, whenever I try to send file, it keeps giving me different error in client and server.

Server side code:

```
public void soc_server() throws IOException {

   long time = System.currentTimeMillis();

    long totalSent = 0;
    ServerSocket servsock = null;
    Socket sock = null;
    PrintWriter pw = null;
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;

    try {

        servsock = new ServerSocket(55000);
        sock = servsock.accept();
        System.out.println("Hello Server");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter the file name or file path");

        String s = sc.nextLine();

        sc.close();

        File file = new File(s);

        if (file.exists())

            System.out.println("File found");
        else
            System.out.println("File not found");

        OutputStream out = sock.getOutputStream();

        pw = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream(), true);

        pw.print(s);

        fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(s);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[100 * 1024];

        int bytesRead = 0;

        while ((bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {

            if (bytesRead > 0) {

                out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

                totalSent += bytesRead;

                System.out.println("sent " + (totalSent / 1024) + " KB "
                        + ((System.currentTimeMillis() - time) / 1000)
                        + " sec");
            }

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {

        System.out.println("exception " + e);

    } finally {
        sock.close();

        pw.close();

        servsock.close();

        fileInputStream.close();

        System.out.println("Sent " + (totalSent / 1024) + " kilobytes in "

        + ((System.currentTimeMillis() - time) / 1000) + " seconds");

    }

}
```

Client Side code:

```
public void soc_client() throws Exception {
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long totalRecieved = 0;
    Socket sock = null;
    InputStream in = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;

    try {
        sock = new Socket("172.16.27.106", 55000);
        System.out.println("Hello Client");
        in = sock.getInputStream();
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String fileName = br.readLine();
        File outputFile = new File(fileName + "");
        fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[100 * 1024];
        int bytesRead = 0;

        while ((bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            totalRecieved += bytesRead;
            System.out.println("Recieved " + (totalRecieved / 1024)
                    + " kilobytes in "
                    + ((System.currentTimeMillis() - time) / 1000)
                    + " seconds");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception " + e);
    } finally {
        br.close(); // CLOSING BufferedReader
        fileOutputStream.close();
        sock.close();
        System.out.println("Recieved " + totalRecieved + " bytes in "
                + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time) + "ms.");
    }
}
```

Exceptions:

Client Side:

```
Exception java.io.FileNotFoundException: Invalid file path
Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException

Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: Invalid file path 
          at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source) 
          at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source) 
          at Client.soc_client(Client.java:25) 
          at Index.main(Index.java:24)
```

Server Side:

```
Exception java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
Exception: java.util.NoSuchElementException
Exception java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe

Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Connection reset 
          at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:113)
          at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153) 
          at Server.soc_server(Server.java:59) 
          at Index.main(Index.java:21)
```

The file I am trying to send is the same directory (Desktop) from which I am compiling the class. 
Thank you.

Comment: Please post the stack trace(s) and indicate the line(s) they were thrown from.

Comment: I have edited the main post with stack trace(s) of both server and client. Please have a look. Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to give file name directly in the path at client side.

```
File outputFile = new File("yourfile.txt");
```

and then send it to server.

Because of exception `FileNotFound` at client side , you are closing the the stream at `finaly` block.

As you are closing the stream of client side, the server side does not recognize the stream from which it is reading hence giving `Connection reset` exception.

As no stream is there for reading data at server side, you are getting `NoSuchElement` exception

**EDIT**

Another thing is, you are not flushing the stream after writing to client,

So do `pw.flush();` after `pw.print(s)` and `out.write()`

Comment: But I want to have the same file name in both client side and server side. How can I ensure that then? Thank you

Comment: Then print the `filename` before reading at client side which you are getting from the server and see if that filename path exist in client system.

Comment: the filepath does not exist. So, I gave outputFile.createNewFile() command again. error still stays.

Comment: Is that file not found exception still coming?

Comment: my actual code were, outputFile.mkdir(); outputFile.createNewFile(); 
Now I have got an empty folder named null and error is still coming. On server side, No Such Element Exception, on client side there is no exception. It appears on the client side, it does not receive anything.

Comment: flushing works. But now the doc file, i am sending through the socket, the words are getting scrambled. Its not in the UTF-8 format.

Comment: @AJ. Why does he need to convert anything to a string before writing it to a file?

Comment: @IbtehazShawon .doc files are binary. Don't use Readers and Writers on binary data. Use streams.

Comment: @EJP yes.. I forgot that

Comment: @EJP, I was using Streams to read file before. The problem solved when I stopped taking input through BufferedReaders for receiving plain text. Now, to send large files like mp4 or avi, can I use Streams? and also cant I send file and plain text through one class?
Thank you.

Comment: @IbtehazShawon post another question, Only one question per thread